# User specific state save in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using `bStateSave=true` to save the current state of the datatable in the page.
But the problem is if any other user logs into the page in the same system then his table will have other user's settings like filter, sort etc....

Is there any way in datatable that we can store the datatable state for specific users.
If one user logs in then his settings should be used like feature?

Comment: Cookies? Database? Plenty of options really.

Comment: If it is what bStateSave is using then we are good. I think this uses cookies..

Comment: i think that you can check `fnCookieCallback` [here](https://datatables.net/ref)

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the state when you log in and access the table first time, or when the last user logged out. See https://datatables.net/reference/api/state.clear%28%29